# Is every algebraic integer a sum of roots of $x^n - a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

A complex number is said to be an algebraic integer if it is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficents.

For example any root of the polynomial $x^n - a$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an algebraic integer. Is any algebraic integer a sum such roots? That is:

> Is any algebraic integer of the form $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_t$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and there exists $n$ such that $a_i^n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It follows that this is false from the same result about algebraic numbers.

Every algebraic number can be written as $\frac{\alpha}n$ where $n$ in an integer and $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.  So if this was true for algebraic integers, it would be also true for algebraic numbers.

The fact that there are algebraic numbers that cannot be expressed in terms of radicals is a foundational result of Galois theory.

Comment: Of course.. so for a concrete counterexample, any root of a monic polynomial from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that is not solvable by radicals works